# A basic question about function space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Im reading Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed. Actually, Carothers has begun his talk of function space since chapter9. However, I haven't found any definition about function space. Here is a definition from wiki, "In mathematics, a function space is a set of functions of a given kind from a set X to a set Y". 
What i'm a little confused by is that for example C[0,1], so Y can be $\mathbb R$ containing all ranges of continuous functions on [0,1], right? I mean Y is just a codomain?

Comment: Yes, $Y$ can be $\mathbb{R}$. Then you will get all real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. If you let $Y =[0,1]$ you get real-valued continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon: make sense. Thanks^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "function space" is not a precise mathematical term like  "Hilbert space" or "Banach space". It is merely an indication that we have a vector space and we are inclined (at least at this moment) to think of its elements as functions, whether or not they actually are. Some examples:

- Is $\ell^2$, the space of square-summable sequences, a function space? Yes, it is (a sequence is a function whose domain is  $\mathbb N$). But hardly anyone actually calls $\ell^2$ a function space; it's a "sequence space".
- Is $L^2[0,1]$ a function space? No, because its elements are not functions but  equivalence classes of functions. Yet, people habitually put it (along with assorted Sobolev, Besov, Morrey, Campanato, etc spaces) into the vast catalog of "function spaces".

One attempt to be more precise is to define a function space as a topological vector space whose elements are functions on some set $X$, and such that   the pointwise evaluation $f\mapsto f(a)$ is a continuous linear functional, for every $a\in X$.  (This was a definition given by one of my professors when I asked him to define a "function space"). In some contexts it   works well, but I would not use it myself: it seems odd to say that the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ is a function space when $kp>n$ and is not a function space when $kp\le n$.

Comment: Thanks^_^. 1. What does "equivalence classes of functions" mean? 2. For example f:X->Y. Metric of space X is d1, metric of space Y is d2 and f, supposed to be in C(X), should be equipped with sup norm, is that right? If so, that means they can be in different metrics, right?

Comment: @Frank_W (1) It means an equivalence class whose members are functions. See [$L^p$ space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces). (2) I don't know what you are talking about. If you have another question, ask it as a question.